# Updating tablesorter columns

Tags: tablesorter

I added a parser to the jquery.tablesorter plugin and it runs correctly and returns the *result* (see code below) but the table is not updating with the parsed results.  Is there a step that I'm missing?  I tried to use this when the page first loads and during a sort on the header:

// this is in my add parser javascript file

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "currencyformat",
    is: function () {
        // does it start with a dollar sign
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
                var text = s;
                if (text.charAt(0) === '$') {
                    var currency = text.split("$");
                    var result = currencyFormat(parseFloat(currency[1]));
                    return result;  // result looks like "$42.00" without extra zeros
                } else { 
                    return text;
                }
    },
    //parsed: true, // filter widget flag 
    type: "text"  // also tried text and numeric
});
```

In my javascript code is set up like this:

```
$('#testtable').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        3: { sorter: 'currencyformat' }, // column # 4
        4: { sorter: 'currencyformat' }, // column # 5
    },
    sortList: [[4, 1]]
});
```

My table looks something like this:
...
    range id type      money1    money1
    abc   1  alphabet  $44.0000  $491.87000
    jkl   2  alphabet  $42.0000  $12.00000
    xyz   3  alphabet  $45.5000  $23.39000

Answer (score 1):

Tablesorter has a built-in currency parser, so all you should need to do is initialize the plugin ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2681/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[1, 1]]
    });
});
```

---

Update: Try this "modColumn" widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2761/)):

It optimizes modifying the contents of the table by removing the tbody, modifying it's contents then adding it back. Hopefully the function example is straight-forward enough that it doesn't need much explanation:

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'modColumn'],
        widgetOptions: {
            modColumn : {
                1 : function( table, $cell, html ){
                    return '$ ' + html + ' USD';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

var modColumn = function(table, c, wo){
    var k, i, $bk, $tb, $cell, n, totalRows, col,
        b = table.tBodies,
        cols = c.columns,
        modColumn = wo.modColumn;
    // if nothing is set, return quickly
    if ($.isEmptyObject(modColumn)) { return; }
    for (k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        $bk = $(b[k]);
        if ($bk.length && !$bk.hasClass(c.cssInfoBlock)) {
            $tb = $.tablesorter.processTbody(table, $bk, true);
            n = c.cache[k].normalized;
            totalRows = n.length;
            for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                for (col in modColumn) {
                    if ($.isFunction(modColumn[col])) {
                        n[i][cols].$row.children().eq(col).html(function(i, h){
                            // put original value into data-text attribute for updates
                            var $t = $(this),
                                orig = $t.attr(c.textAttribute) || '';
                            if (orig === '') {
                                $t.attr(c.textAttribute, h);
                                orig = h;
                            }
                            return modColumn[col]( table, $(this), orig );
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            $.tablesorter.processTbody(table, $tb, false);
        }
    }
};

$.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: "modColumn",
    options: {
        modColumn : {}
    },
    init: function(table, thisWidget, c, wo) {
        c.$table
            .off('.modColumn')
            .on('update updateRows updateAll addRows '.split(' ').join('.modColumn '), function(){
                modColumn(table, c, wo);
            });
        modColumn(table, c, wo);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks.  Unfortunately in my case I can't place $ or , on the server b/c other apps use the webapi differently.  I need to apply the currency format on the client side.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't place $ or , on the server"? The code I posted will work with your table as-is... no change to the table content is needed.

Comment: Did not mean to offend... since all the data is on the server when I place the content:<tr>
            <td>zyx 24</td>
            <td>$76.75</td>
            <td>Bison</td>
            <td>http://www.whitehouse.gov/</td>
        </tr>  I want to leave off the "$" coming from the server.

Comment: LOL I wasn't offended. So you want to add the "$"? You'll probably need to do that before initializing tablesorter.

Comment: Problem is the table is big enough it causes a noticable delay before or after tablesorter is initialized.  My preferred solution is to use the addWidget functionality to intercept the cell and add $ and commas.  That way we only have one javascript function that performs the formatting of the number.

Comment: A formatter widget for tablesorter is now available; it allows you to format column text & perform other manipulations to the cell. Check out [the demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-formatter.html).